# Twitter bootstrap menu mobile menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying hard to understand how the menu system works on airtasker.com website. I need a similar menu for a site. can we achieve it using boostrap. the links/icons are changed from web to mobile screen.

I have made the basic collapse menu, but struggling to make it work as on airtasker.com site.

help will be appreciated.

Regards
Paraminder

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: Can you share you code - what you have tried and where you are facing problem..

Answer (score 0):

Check this may be this works for you..

```
  <header class="navbar navbar-default" id="top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="../">
                 <img alt="Brand" src="../Images/B.png" /> </a>
            </div>
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="../getting-started/">Getting started</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../css/">CSS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../components/">Components</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../javascript/">JavaScript</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../customize/">Customize</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```